# Custom number format for NULL

Tags: excel, formatting, excel-formula

I have an excel sheet that I populate from a database. What is the custom number format that I can use to replace NULL values in the excel by a hyphen '-' ?
I know that I can use the following formula

```
#,##0_);(#,##0);–_);_(@_)
```

in order to display it for a zero. But I don't know how to handle a null value.

Comment: custom number formats only allow you to format numeric values

Comment: @pnuts, thats what I thought... but its a big table.. only if i don't have any other choice, I would replace them with zeros. leaving blank cells in excel might be a better choice in that case.

Comment: Find/Replace all "NULL" with ""?

Comment: i am doing it programatically  via interop in c#. Performance might take a hit.. An "NULL" doesnt show up in excel.. its just a blank cell and I want to display '-'

Comment: @pnuts Yup got that; OP was suggesting "leaving blank cells in excel might be a better choice.." so that was a quickie for that. That's what i get for jumping into the conversation :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simple answer is that the number format strings do not have a section for NULL values.  See ECMA-376 section 18.8.31 for an explanation:

> Up to four sections of format codes can be specified. The format codes, separated by semicolons, define the formats for positive numbers, negative numbers, zero values, and text, in that order. If only two sections are specified, the first is used for positive numbers and zeros, and the second is used for negative numbers. If only one section is specified, it is used for all numbers.

One workaround is to check for null values, emit a text value, and set the text format.  For example, using the formula `0;0;0;"-"`:

```
VALUE    FORMATTED
#NULL!   -
NULL     -
1        1
2        2
3        3
4        4
```

Note that this only works if you expect the result to be numerical.  If you expect a string value, you can do the opposite (`"-";"-";"-";@`)